# Shadows created by :after and :before overlap parent onHover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

**Background Information:**

I have a page full of bootstrap 3 `.thumbnail` elements with content inside. I have used CSS to add a `box-shadow` to the element:

```
.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 97%; /*Needed to show box shadow*/
  border: 2px solid $subdued;
  margin: 0 2px 15px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  background: $bg-color;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #FFF, #F9F9F9);
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  @include transition(all, 0.4s, ease);

  &:before, &:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    @include transform( rotate(-3deg) );
    @include transition(all, 0.1s, ease);
  }

  &:after {
    @include transform( rotate(3deg) );
    right: 10px;
    left: auto;
  }
}
```

Note: The `@include` statements are just SASS mixins there for vendor prefixing; there's nothing relevant to the issue baked-into the mixin.

This CSS works well until I add some code for a hover state; when the user hovers over a `.thumbnail` I want all other `.thumbnail` elements to reduce their `opacity` to 0.4. To that end, I have added the following CSS:

```
.deckgrid:hover .thumbnail:not(:hover) { opacity: 0.4 }
.deckgrid:hover .thumbnail:not(:hover):before,
.deckgrid:hover .thumbnail:not(:hover):after { opacity: 0; }
```

Note: `.deckgrid` is just a wrapper `<div>` for the `.thumbnail`s.

**The Problem:**

When I hover over a `.thumbnail`, that particular `.thumbnail` behaves as intended; however, all the other thumbnails on the page are overlapped by their `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements for about a second before correcting themselves. This causes the transition to look jerky and weird.

Any ideas on how this might be fixed?

Comment: create a demo it will be helpful (snippet or fiddle)

Comment: Hrm...for some reason...codepen doesn't seem to repeat the error... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogzNZM?editors=110 But the exact same code in my browser does...

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to replicate it. See the link in my previous comment.